# Looping through multiple elements and calculating price discount for each

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, dom

I am trying to find the percentage difference between the old and new price of each individual `<div>`. At the minute, my code is only pulling through the percentage difference of the first `<div>` and looping the same percentage difference to the rest of the `<div>`s. Does anyone know how I can update this to target each individual `<div>` rather than just looping through the first one? I would like to do this in pure JavaScript; no jQuery please.

```js
const priceDifference = () => {
  const regPrice = document.querySelector('.old').innerText;
  const salePrice = document.querySelector('.new').innerText;

  const priceNumReg = parseFloat(regPrice.substring(1));
  const priceNumSale = parseFloat(salePrice.substring(1));
  const finalPrice = priceNumReg - priceNumSale;

  const percentage = document.querySelectorAll('.percentage');
  const percent = (finalPrice / priceNumReg) * 100;

  for (i = 0; i < percentage.length; i++) {
    if (percentage[i].textContent.trim() === '') {
      percentage[i].textContent += ' (' + percent.toFixed(0) + '% OFF)';
    }
  }
};

priceDifference();
```

```html
<div class="price">
  <div class="old">$14.00</div>
  <div class="new">$6.00</div>
  <div class="percentage"></div>
</div>

<div class="price">
  <div class="old">$12.00</div>
  <div class="new">$5.00</div>
  <div class="percentage"></div>
</div>

<div class="price">
  <div class="old">$18.00</div>
  <div class="new">$3.00</div>
  <div class="percentage"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have to loop through each `.price` element, not each `.percentage`. Do all the calculations _inside_ the loop and use [`priceElement.querySelector`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector), not [`document.querySelector`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).

Comment: @SebastianSimon const price = document.querySelectorAll('.price');
    for (i = 0; i < price.length; i++) {
        const regPrice = price[i].querySelector('.old').innerText;
        const salePrice = price[i].querySelector('.new').innerText;
        const percentage = price[i].querySelectorAll('.percentage');
        const percent = (finalPrice / priceNumReg) * 100; 
        if (percentage.textContent.trim() === '') {
            percentage.textContent += ' ('+ percent.toFixed(0) + '% OFF)';
        }
    }

Comment: @SebastianSimon sorry thankyou for replying. Is the above comment what you mean by this? It's not recognising my .innerText now when I loop this way

Comment: No - don't use `querySelectorAll` on the inner loop - you only want one element, so `querySelector` inside the loop.  You also haven't moved `priceNumReg` inside the loop.  I suggest you change "price" variables to prices rather than have a "priceNum" - if you want both then have one as "priceText" = innerText and `regPrice` = prase(priceTxt)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to loop through each `.price` element, not each `.percentage`, since each individual calculation you’re trying to perform is based on the scope of a single `<div class="price">`.
Do all the calculations *inside* the loop, say for the current `priceElement` (which is one of your `<div class="price">` elements).
Now you can use [`priceElement.querySelector`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector), instead of [`document.querySelector`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).
`document.querySelector` finds the first matching element in the entire document, whereas `priceElement.querySelector` will find the first matching element inside that scope: `priceElement`.

So the function would look more like this:

```js
const priceDifference = () => {
  const price = document.querySelectorAll(".price");

  for (i = 0; i < price.length; i++) {
    const priceElement = price[i];

    const regPrice = priceElement.querySelector(".old").innerText;
    const salePrice = priceElement.querySelector(".new").innerText;
    const percentage = priceElement.querySelector(".percentage");

    const priceNumReg = parseFloat(regPrice.substring(1));
    const priceNumSale = parseFloat(salePrice.substring(1));

    const finalPrice = priceNumReg - priceNumSale;
    const percent = (finalPrice / priceNumReg) * 100;
    
    if (percentage.textContent.trim() === '') {
      percentage.textContent += ' (' + percent.toFixed(0) + '% OFF)';
    }
  }
};
```

This code *works*, but there’s still a bit of work that needs to be done, e.g. the missing declaration for `i` and [`innerText` vs. `textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText), but this code can also be shortened like this:

```js
const parseCurrencyValue = ({ textContent }) => Number.parseFloat(textContent.replace(/^[^-+0-9.]*/u, "")),
  priceDifference = () => Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".price"))
  .forEach((priceElement) => {
    const [
        regularPrice,
        salePrice
      ] = [ ".old", ".new" ]
        .map((selector) => parseCurrencyValue(priceElement.querySelector(selector))),
      discount = 1 - (salePrice / regularPrice),
      percentageElement = priceElement.querySelector(".percentage");

    if (percentageElement.textContent.trim() === "") {
      percentageElement.insertAdjacentText("beforeend", ` (${Math.round(discount * 100)} % off)`);
    }
  });

priceDifference();
```

```css
.percentage {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div class="price">
  <div class="old">$14.00</div>
  <div class="new">$6.00</div>
  <div class="percentage"></div>
</div>

<div class="price">
  <div class="old">$12.00</div>
  <div class="new">$5.00</div>
  <div class="percentage"></div>
</div>

<div class="price">
  <div class="old">$18.00</div>
  <div class="new">$3.00</div>
  <div class="percentage"></div>
</div>
```

I’ve grouped the `const`s, used some [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), and avoided some code repetition.
I’ve used a `map` over the selectors `.new` and `.old` since they need to be treated identically; this is how you would generally avoid code repetition: put everything that is *the same* into its own set of functions, and iterate only over the stuff that changes, passing it as arguments to the function.
The discount calculation can also be simplified.

But most importantly:

You should use `Array.from(`*some NodeList*`).forEach` to iterate over the result of `querySelectorAll`.
This is a bit more robust since you don’t need to mess around with `for` loop syntax anymore; the syntax is more expressive this way.

You should split the process of parsing text as a price into its own function; that’s `parseCurrencyValue` in my example.
I’ve also used a more robust regular expression that’ll work for strings like `"$ 12.99"`, `"USD 12.99"`, `"12.99 $"`, etc., by removing anything that isn’t part of a number from the start, then using [`Number.parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/parseFloat).

You should not put “OFF” literally into a string.
You’re trying to communicate that something is *50 percent off*, so the correct spelling would be “off”.
Transforming this into all-caps should be done in CSS; this way it’s more accessible and screen readers don’t get confused by what “[O.F.F.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off)” might be.

There might also be some semantic HTML improvements, but this requires a bit more context.
Ideally, the data is structured in a table, not in some arbitrary `<div>`s.

Comment: Thankyou so much for taking the time to help me understand this! This is the best answer I could ask for with so much added detail. Thankyou so much!